# Two Submit Buttons - node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I only know how to do a single post function from a node js app. I want to implement a like and dislike function but I can only do one at a time. Here's the html code:

```
<form method="post" name="ratings">
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="like">
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="dislike">
</form>
```

I can do a single post function, but how would I split it up depending on the html button selection. Can I extract the value in my index.ts file. I'm working in typescript, and this is the first line of the index.ts code that I would begin with

```
router.post('/testpage/*', function (req, res) {
```

Comment: On the server-side you should be testing the value being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `vote` in the request, then execute the proper code for each. In your setup, you'll want to examine `req.body.vote` with either a switch, or an if statement logic chain.